# c++ Sphinx rt_attr_string truncates data

Tags: sphinx

I'm inserting the content of my documents in an `rt_attr_string` field. I have declared the `max_packet_size` as `128M`.

However, my input string of `5075850` characters is truncated to a string of `881546` characters. How is this possible and how can I overcome this unexpected behavior? I have already checked the inserted strings. They contain valid characters between `a-Z, 0-9` and `_ ;` or `?`

Therefore, why is Sphinx behaving like this? The queried value is directly queried after the insert statement has executed. Therefore, it seems that Sphinx has some issues?

I have logged the query and the queried values, which can be seen in this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6hrd835kbo7ndd/example.txt?dl=0)

***Please note, I insert encrypted values since this is a requirement in my project. My software is perfectly capable of keeping all Sphinx functionalities, but this seems to be a Sphinx related issue since the inserted value differs from the returned value by Sphinx?***

The configuration of my index is:

```
index Test
{
  type            = rt
  path            = /mnt/data001/Test
  rt_field        = Name
  rt_field        = Extension
  rt_field        = Content
  rt_field        = Tags
  rt_attr_uint    = Reference
  rt_attr_uint    = FileSize
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModified
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedYear
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedMonth
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedDay
  rt_attr_string  = Content
  rt_mem_limit    = 1024M
  charset_table   = A..Z, a..z, 0..9, _, ;, %
  ondisk_attrs    = pool
}

searchd
{
  listen                = 9306:mysql41
  log                   = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  read_timeout          = 5
  max_children          = 30
  pid_file              = /var/run/searchd.pid
  max_packet_size       = 128M
  binlog_path           = /mnt/data001
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. You should create a simple example: an empty Sphinx index and a script which writes a big string into it and then reads it and compares the results.

Comment: @hank, alright. Could you maybe tell me or there are any limits on the `rt_attr_string`? Because, I can't discover a relation with the length of the returned string... (0.8MB at this point)

Comment: I don't know exact limits, but in my test I successfully wrote and read back `5075850` characters.

Comment: @hank, how is that possible? My insert ‘fails’ each try. Do you use my configuration as well?

Comment: @hank, could you share your configuration?

Comment: @hank, I have reproduced the issue in an empty index (even on another machine. Returning exact the same amount of characters as the other index on another machine did). Could it possible be due to the MySQL version? I currently use version 5.7.22. Could you please share your configuration of both sphinx and the MySQL version used? Also important, are you using a prepared statement to insert the values or just the plain query as I have shown in the log file? Thanks

Comment: @hank could you please share your configuration? This is of major importance for our troubleshooting. I have already been tweaking my configuration, but haven't been able to insert the string successfully

Comment: I used Sphinx 3.1.1, your exact config and a python script to insert a string.

Comment: @hank alright, thanks for the response. Though, in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362345/sphinx-insert-seems-truncated-but-no-errors-found/53368355?noredirect=1#comment93618643_53368355) they claim that `rt_attr_string` has the same limit as `sql_attr_string`, being 4MB per value. How are you able to store the entire string then? This confuses me a bit...? Who is correct regarding this issue, because both contradict each other?

Comment: And again. I took Sphinx 3.1.1, your config, your example query from dropbox and everything worked as expected.

Comment: @hank are you sure that the returned string is indeed the inserted string for 100%? Because, others claim that Sphinx truncates the string when it's over 4MB of length..? So you are both contradicting each other and I get the situation the others tell me about?... Could you please double check that the returned string is indeed the inserted string without being truncated?

Comment: Here's my script and its output: https://gist.github.com/hanky/1e5746529f1eb7d75067aa468f2e2a3c

Comment: @hank thanks for the response. Do you use DocStore in your version? Since I use Sphinx 2.x which doesn't support DocStore yet

Comment: Ohh. I already said twice that I used **3.1.1** and your **exact** config. Sphinx 2 is not supported anymore. Even if it really has any bugs or limitations, nobody will fix them.

Comment: @hank, but if I install Sphinx via APT on Ubuntu I still get Sphinx 2.x served? Can you point me to the installation files for Sphinx 3.1.1 for Ubuntu? Also, the SphinxSearch repositories don't include any 3.x version? `Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'sphinxsearch-beta':  sphinxsearch-beta
 * 'sphinxsearch-daily':  sphinxsearch-daily
 * 'sphinxsearch-rel20':  sphinxsearch-rel20
 * 'sphinxsearch-rel21':  sphinxsearch-rel21
 * 'sphinxsearch-rel22':  sphinxsearch-rel22
 * 'sphinxsearch-rel23':  sphinxsearch-rel23
 * 'sphinxsearch-stable':  sphinxsearch-stable`

Comment: @hank I can't get Sphinx3 to work. How do I install this binary? I can't specify a configuration file for the searchd daemon and it fails to locate my old config file for Sphinx 2.x